# Combining multiple rows into one row where the data in only one column changes and adding the data for the varied column onto the end of the row

Tags: sql

I was hoping you could help me as my sql is very basic. Below is my query:

I have data that looks like this:

```
Policy Number | Commission Amount | Relationship | PersonLinked
50422         | 1000.00           | Owner        | John Smith
50422         | 1000.00           | Advisor      | Richard Bass
50422         | 1000.00           | Port Man     | Craig Thomson
74857         | 500.00            | Owner        | Karen Jones
98765         | 20000.00          | Owner        | Tim Crosby
98765         | 20000.00          | Port Man     | Josh Bishop
```

BUT I want to display all of the data in one row so it looks like this:

```
Policy Number | Commission Amount | Owner          | Advisor        | Port Man
50422         | 1000.00           | John Smith     | Richard Bass   | Craig Thomson
74857         | 500.00            | Karen Jones    |                |
98765         | 20000.00          | Tim Crosby     |                | Josh Bishop
```

If it is possible to manipulate the data in this way, please let me know what the SQL would be.  I am really stuck. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried?  We generally don't write the code for you; you need to show some effort in attempting to figure it out.  I'll give you a hint and say you're looking for using a pivot or CASE statements. but without knowing what RDBMS your using, we can't write the SQL.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890467/split-rows-into-12-columns or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599404/rows-into-columns

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a fixed, static number of relationships, known from the beginning, then the answer is: NO. You cannot make SQL queries that return variable number of columns.

Your chances are:
 - if you are using a proprietary SQL rdbms, there might be some pivoting functionality
 - if you are using any kind of language (like PHP, VBA) to create the query - then you can create it in a dynamically, after querying for possible relationships.

Comment: @xQbert: this is exactly what I have written in my anser: either pivot (proprietary) or using dynamically created query (depending on the technology used it might be called differently; "dynamic SQL", "string concatenation", whatever). Did you have a point in repeating my answer in your comment?

Comment: I am confused by your first stating it can't be done unless its fixed number of columns, then proceed to explain how it can be done for a variable number of columns.  The OP didn't impose any limits on how to accomplish the desired results that I see; so when I read "NO it can't be done" I disagreed.

Comment: @xQbert: I simply stated that it cannot be done in SQL - and the reason why. The question is tagged "SQL", no specific vendor or scripting language is mentioned. Plain "no" could be the end of my answer, but I felt it wasn't complete without reminding that in the real life we usually have more tools than SQL: like some sort of environment for generating SQL queries on the fly (any procedural language will do). Or some RDBMS extension (like pivot). Are you still confused? Anything more I can explain?

Comment: no.  Any further conversation will not aid in providing an answer to the problem.

Comment: @xQbert: thank you, you have displayed class and tact that I lacked. EOT.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you have one of each role per policy number, and that the only roles that you need to show are these three.

```
Select [own].[Policy Number], 
       [own].[Commission Amount],
       [own].[PersonLinked] as [Owner],
       [adv].[PersonLinked] as [Advisor],
       [port].[PersonLinked] as [Port Man]
From   PolicyRoles as [own]
Join   PolicyRoles as [adv] on [own].[Policy Number] = [adv].[Policy Number]
                            and [adv].[Relationship] = 'Advisor'
Join   PolicyRoles as [port] on [own].[Policy Number] = [port].[Policy Number]
                             and [port].[Relationship] = 'Port Man'
Where  [own].[Relationship] = 'Owner'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Select a.Policy Number, a.Commission Amount, a.PersonLinked as 'Owner', b.PersonLinked 'Advisor', c.PersonLinked as 'Port Man' 
FROM tbl a, tbl b, tbl c
WHERE a.Policy Number = b.Policy Number AND a.Policy Number = c.Policy Number AND
b.Policy Number = c.Policy Number AND a.Relationship = 'Owner' AND 
b.Relationship = 'Advisor' AND c.Relationship = 'Port Man';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your answer depends on the version of SQL, which you did not specify. There are functions in every version that allow you to concat. values, e.g. convert table data to string. In Oracle - LISTAGG(), MY SQL - GROUP_CONCAT() etc... Creating dynamic columns in SQL is not possible unless you create a view or table for each of your cases. You can create table as select all columns you need and add more columns from your_table, you can also create views with different number of column. You need to research this in your version of SQL. All those examples with CASE expressions are good, but I'd do research and see what is available in your version of SQL beacause LISTAGG() or GROUP_CONCAT() are what you are really looking for, not CASE. Here's Oracle example of creating "dynamic" columns. The emp table is existing table used by Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab AS
 SELECT empno
      , ename
      , ename "OWNER" -- This column name is OWNER and datatype is the same as ename 
  FROM scott.emp
 WHERE 1=2 -- False - empty table is created, no data...
/

-- Describe newly created table:

SQL> desc test_tab  

Column Name  Data Type 
--------------------------------
EMPNO    NUMBER (4)              
ENAME    VARCHAR2 (10 Byte)        
OWNER    VARCHAR2 (10 Byte)
```